# cannot attach to service manager-error

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I am new in firebird and I would like to trace my firebird-database activities, hence I am trying to use Audit/Trace Services.

My firbird databse is on Server: 10.7.105.8
I am running this comman in my cmd:

```
C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin>fbtracemgr -se     10.7.105.8:3050:service_mgr -user SYSDBA -password masterkey -start -name "User Trace 1" -config "fbtrace.conf" > C:\Users\Babak\Desktop\trace.out
```

but I get this error:

```
Can not attach to service manager 
Service 3050 : Service_mgr is not defined
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

thank you so much

**EDIT**

thank you for your hints. I think my trace process works fine, but I cant find the information, what I need in my trace.out file

If I am starting my trace my command promp looks like this:

[image]

if in this step I take a look in my `trace.out` I can only see this:

```
Trace Session ID 3 Started
```

I am running some select queries in my firebird, and then I finish my trace with with ctr+c, then the only things, which I can see in my trace.out are something like this:

```
Trace session ID 3 started
2015-07-08 10:49:59.868874 ***** loading fbclient.dll proc=4116 64Bit DLL Preload
2015-07-08 10:49:59.869066 GetDllDirectoryA=""
2015-07-08 10:49:59.869075 GetModuleFileNameA="C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbclient.dll"
2015-07-08 10:49:59.869086 Log-Level is set to 0
2015-07-08 10:49:59.869096 fbclient.dll loaded by: C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbtracemgr.exe
2015-07-08 10:49:59.869113 ***** dimensio integration successfully fbclient.dll 

2015-07-08 10:58:10.091330 ***** cleanup unload fbclientorg.dll proc=4116
```

and not more infos about queries, which I have run. 
Could you please say me, what I have done wrong? or what should I do more?

Comment: If the error message starts with “Cannot attach to services manager”, the server may not be running at all. In that case, go back to Testing your installation and fix the problem.http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg2-config.html

Comment: Or check firewall for exception. there should be exception on port 3050 on the server.

Comment: One needs to use a slash for port number separation: `fbtracemgr -se 10.7.105.8/3050:service_mgr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mark says, check file "fbtrace.conf". This is a text file and you will see something like this:

```
# default database section 
#
<database>
# Do we trace database events or not
enabled false

# Operations log file name. For use by system audit trace only
#log_filename  
....
....

# Put transaction start/end records 
log_transactions false  <--- TO TEST, SET THIS TO TRUE 


# Put sql statement prepare records 
log_statement_prepare false <-- TO TEST, SET THIS TO TRUE
```

Set to `true` what you need to trace, save the file and check the result.

Answer (score 1):

Firebird connection strings are of the format:

```
host/port:database
```

Where `/port` is optional and defaults to 3050, and database is either the alias or path of a database, or the name of a service. Replace `:3050` with `/3050` (or leave it off entirely).

Comment: @Kaja I think that you should revert your edit and create a new question. The cause is probably that the configuration in fbtrace.conf in the installation of Firebird by default doesn't trace anything (I think, not entirely sure).

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

1. Open start menu
2. Search for services and open it
3. Search Firebird Guardian in the services list.
4. Start Firebird Guardian if it is stopped or restart if it is running.
5. Now try to connect your server. It will work.